# using sed to substitute a string

Tags: regex, string, sed

I have a line like this :

```
 22.665774 Fr RMSG  0 0 1 1 18 11 Rx 0 308002 5  20  1d6 x 20 20 a8 4f 35 40 1b 00 0f 08 f7 89 ff fa ff f3 35 80 49 00 00 00 00 30 00 00 80 ab 4b 54 40 f0 00 fc 714a81  1  40937
```

I want to parse it and substitute it in such a way to get only this part :

```
a8 4f 35 40 1b 00 0f 08 f7 89 ff fa ff f3 35 80 49 00 00 00 00 30 00 00 80 ab 4b 54 40 f0 00 fc
```

At this moment i am using this :

```
sed -re \"s/^.+x//\
```

But this only gives me the part before x.. can you give me some hints please?

Thanks .

Comment: What's the pattern of it? Everything from "a8"? The nth field?

Comment: delete all before a8 and at the end.. eliminate this part : 714a81  1  40937

Comment: Do you always have `a8` there or can it be different? Or is it just for this one line?

Comment: it can be different, that x is important and those two hex strings before a8. So when i got x hex hex .. delete them and what's before them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regular expression:

```
\sx\s(?:[0-9a-f]{2}\s){2}(.*?)\s\w{3,}
```

This will return the part you want in a caught group. Tested [here](http://regex101.com/r/eD6zM0).

Comment: This will fail if the `x` is followed by non-digit characters, i.e. `e1`.

Comment: @mart1n Right, the OP mentioned hex earlier which I overlooked. Fixed now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be sed? [`cut`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/cut/) does it perfectly.

```
echo '22.665774 Fr RMSG  0 0 1 1 18 11 Rx 0 308002 5  20  1d6 x 20 20 a8 4f 35 40 1b 00 0f 08 f7 89 ff fa ff f3 35 80 49 00 00 00 00 30 00 00 80 ab 4b 54 40 f0 00 fc 714a81  1  40937' | cut -d' ' -f22-53
```

Comment: +1 right tool for right job. cut is the way to go for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this expression to match the whole line and capture the strings aftex `x <hex> <hex>`:

```
.*?\sx\s\w*?\s\w*?\s(.*?)\s\w{4,}.*
```

This assumes the `x` is always the delimiter where you want to cut off the remainder of the string.

**Edit**:

Full command to do this on the command line:

```
echo " 22.665774 Fr RMSG  0 0 1 1 18 11 Rx 0 308002 5  20  1d6 x 20 20 a8 4f 35 40 1b 00 0f 08 f7 89 ff fa ff f3 35 80 49 00 00 00 00 30 00 00 80 ab 4b 54 40 f0 00 fc 714a81  1  40937" | perl -pe "s/.*?\sx\s\w*?\s\w*?\s(.*?)\s\w{4,}.*/\1/"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with sed but this applies in the general regex case:

This regex will match the string `"a8 ... fc"` where `"..."` can be any combination of hex-bytes (only lower case letters) and spaces:

```
/a8([0-9a-f ]+)fc/
```

You can then use substitution in the same regex using:

```
/a8$1fc/
```

Here `$1` will be substituted with the match in between the parentheses `([0-9a-f ]+)`.